# what I didn't write here correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have to make an application on the Redux-React. But unfortunately I have error:And these are the main project files:< 
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
[image]

And these are the main project files:

app.js(component):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchData } from '../actions';
import TableData from "./TableData";
import TableSearch from "./TableSearch";

export function searchFilter (search, data) {                                               
  return data.filter(n => n.term.toLowerCase().includes(search));
}

const days = ["23-08-2019", "24-08-2019", "25-08-2019"];        

class Root extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchData(this.props.day);
  }

  render() {
    const { search, shift, data, filteredData, onFilter, onSetSearch, onFetchData } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <TableSearch value={search}
          onChange={(e) => onSetSearch(e.target.value)} 
          onSearch={() => onFilter()} />

        {days.map((day, i) => (
          <button key={day} 
            onClick={() => onFetchData(day)}
            className={i === day ? "active" : ""}>{day}</button>
        ))}
        <br />
        {Object.keys(data).map(n => (
          <button data-shift={n}
            onClick={(e) => onFilter({ shift: e.target.dataset.shift })}
            className={n === shift ? "active" : ""}>{n} shift</button>
        ))}

        <TableData data={filteredData} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const ConnectedRoot = connect(             
  (state) => state,
  (dispatch) => ({
    onFilter: (args) => dispatch({ type: 'RUN_FILTER', ...args }),
    onSetSearch: (search) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_SEARCH', search }),
    onFetchData: (day) => dispatch(fetchData(day))
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get data undefined at initial render, first check if data is available and then map through the data:

```
data && Object.keys(data).map()
```

---

As per your request, you should use return statement in app.js like:

```
return (
      <div>
        <TableSearch value={search}
          onChange={(e) => onSetSearch(e.target.value)} 
          onSearch={() => onFilter()} />

        {days && days.map((day, i) => (
          <button key={day} 
            onClick={() => onFetchData(day)}
            className={i === day ? "active" : ""}>{day}</button>
        ))}
        <br />
        {data && Object.keys(data).map(n => (
          <button data-shift={n}
            onClick={(e) => onFilter({ shift: e.target.dataset.shift })}
            className={n === shift ? "active" : ""}>{n} shift</button>
        ))}

        {data && <TableData data={filteredData} /> }

      </div>
    );
```

Comment: How to do it? Tell please where and how to write the code

Comment: Where you've used Object.keys(data)

Comment: In code please demonstrate I'm new to programming because what you're saying is unfortunately a little help

Comment: It's your code. And you can't find that code? In the app.js I meant.

Comment: you do not understand, I mean write please how to write it in my code

Comment: Just replace Object.keys(data) with data && Object.keys(data)

Comment: trust me it will be faster if you just write the edit file in response, because I did not understand what and where to write so that there was no error

Comment: updated my answer, if you still see error then let me know.

Comment: it has changed nothing,same error:./src/reducers/airplanes.js
  Line 27:32:  'data' is not defined  no-undef. 
Can you watch my sandbox? Maybe there is another reason? 
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-phrs3